# Android custom layout(alert) in service (similar to messenger)

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is simply how can i do a dialog pop up from other application.
I search around and many answer is NO.

However, the messenger like Whaxxapp is exactly doing this. It can pop up an instantly reply while i am playing game, taking picture and etc. (like pausing)

And i had do some research and works,
i am able to create a service which start from my activity (activity A).
And the service is registered a contentobserver, when the observer onchange is fired, it can launch an activity(pendingactivity B) and the activity B which i had set the theme transparent and look like a dialog popup. however, it will also change the background back to my activity A and with the popup as well.

What i want to do is not go back to my activity A and just pop up (or launch the pending activity B) when i receive an onchange. (same as Whaxxapp pop up message with interaction)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start Activity B to new task. So when you press back activity A won't be shown. Add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to Activity B intent.

Comment: i found that if i am in Activity A and press home, no matter i am using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, the onchange event fired, the Activity A will show together with the Activity B(popup). However, if my Activity A is not exist, (press back when i am in Activity A) the Activity A will not be shown. Is it normal?? and here is my codesnap inside the onchange. 
application is the the "services and declare in the constructor.


  Intent update = new Intent(application, StartAlertActivity.class);
 update.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
 application.startActivity(update);

Comment: finaly it seems success when i add one more flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
thanks your answer inspiring me...

Comment: sometimes it is hard to give exact answer... I misunderstood your question a little. You are welcome )

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but I think the Whatsapp "Popup" is actually an Activity styled to look like a Dialog.

You can do this changing an Activity's theme to:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

You can then add Button's, etc, just like a normal Activity to add interaction.

Comment: My Problem is not popup an dialog like activity, my problem is cannot JUST popup the dialog when the foreground is other application. And it will change the foreground to my original activity and show the new activity.